# Windows Forms ComboBox DataBinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I'm working on a C# Windows Forms Application and my ComboBox DataBinding is not working correctly.

This is my Data Source[image: Form Data Source]

And this is how Data Source is filled.

```
private void frmSODetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int soid = soSelected.soid;
        this.salesordersTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsSalesOrderDetails.salesorders, soid);
        this.solineitemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsSalesOrderDetails.solineitems, soid);
        this.companiesTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsSalesOrderDetails.companies);
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

This is my form
[image: Sales Order Details Form]

And this is how i do the DataBindings.
Select Data Source (companiesBindingSource)
[image: Selecting Data Source]
Selecting Display Member (compname)
[image: Selecting Display Member]
Selecting Value Member (seq)
[image]
Selecting Selected Value (Column comp from salesordersBindingSource)
[image]
To Make Sure (Selected Value: comp) and (Value Member: seq) matches i used Preview Data

Comp : 1
[image]
Seq 1 should have a compname value of **Ampleon**
[image]

But the ComboBox does not show **Ampleon** it shows the first item on the list of Companies.
[image]

EDIT: I deleted the entire form and created a new one and it is working properly now. I am not sure what went wrong on the first form. I just followed the same steps.

Comment: did you try set ValueMember and SelectedValue to `comp` from SalesOrders table?

Comment: i cannot set the ValueMember to `comp` from SalesOrders table because the DataSource for my ComboBox is `companiesBindingSource` . I can only select from the columns available in my binding source.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong column field to a texbox. Instead of calling the second column which stores your field data, you are calling the first column which I suppose it is an incremented field.. You should do it programmatically.
Refer to this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984341(v=vs.71).aspx it will give you a headstart 
See if it helps

Comment: Im not sure what you meant. But to clarify, I am filling a ComboBox. The DataSource is table `SalesOrders` containing a column field for `comp`. Instead of storing the `compname` directly into the `SalesOrders` i have a separate table called `companies`. Table `SalesOrder` and table `companies` are related to each other such that the value in `SalesOrder.comp` is equals to `companies.seq`

Comment: In this case, I am filling the Combox with the List of Companies from Table `companies` the DisplayMember is the Company Name (`compname`) and the ValueMember is Company Unique Identifier named (`seq`). The SelectedValue is binded to Table `salesorder` column field `comp` which contains the integer values equivalent to the Company Unique Identifier (`seq`)

Comment: In my case. I will create a view function to get my desired result. Then call the field from the created view to your combobox where the column field from salesorder ID = companies ID